# Reading a GZIP file from a FileChannel (Java NIO)

Tags: java, zip, gzip, nio, filechannel

I need to read/unpack a .gz file given a FileChannel.

I've played around with extracting GZIP archives using GZIPInputStream, but this won't take a FileChannel. I don't have access to the original FileInputStream that the FileChannel was taken from.

If someone could tell me a good way (or at least *any* way) of reading GZIP from a FileChannel, I would greatly appreciate it.

*Adapted from a question on the [<strike>Sun</strike> Oracle forums](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5334496).*

Answer (score 20):

You could obtain a wrapping InputStream around the FileChannel:

```
FileChannel fc = ...
GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(Channels.newInputStream(fc));
```

[Channels](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channels.html) is in Java SE.

Comment: This worked great!. Combined this with the answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080381/gzipinputstream-reading-line-by-line. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there is a solution. Implementing GZip is fairly simple. You need a Inflater and CRC32, plus reading the header/trailer. Unfortunately `java.util.zip.Inflater` takes only `byte[]` which is suboptimal (a direct Buffer would have been times more efficient). Yet, using non-direct buffer and ByteBuffer.array() is an option.

The built in `java.util.zip.CRC32` is quite slow and [reimplementing it in java](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12413610/PureJavaCrc32NewLoop.java) is a nice step towards performance.  `com.jcraft.jzlib` [offers pure java implementation](http://www.jcraft.com/jzlib/) (almost looks like pure C, though) and it's possible to replace the byte[] w/ direct Buffer. The library is somewhat slower compared to inflater (decomppress) due to too many bounds check and inability to perform so deep inline. Yet, it's faster on compression.