# NIO GZIP compression and copying of files

Tags: java, filechannel, gzipinputstream, gzipoutputstream

I was using `FileChannel` and `FileInputStream` to do a simple file copying from `File` fromFile to `File` toFile.

The code is basically like this:

```
source = new FileInputStream(fromFile).getChannel();
destination = new FileOutputStream(toFile, false).getChannel(); // overwrite
destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
```

where `fromFile` and `toFile` are proper `File` objects.
Now, instead of copying from `fromFile` directly, i wanted to compress its content using GZIP (found in Java libraries) and then copy to `toFile`. Also reversely, when I transfer back from `toFile`, I would like to decompress it as well.

I was wondering is there a simple way like

```
source = new GZIPCompressInputStream(new FileInputStream(fromFile)).getChannel();
```

or

```
source = new GZIPDecompressInputStream(new FileInputStream(fromFile)).getChannel();
```

and all the rest of code remain unchanged. Do you have any suggestion on the cleanest solution to this?

Thanks..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading a GZIP file from a FileChannel (Java NIO)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335969/reading-a-gzip-file-from-a-filechannel-java-nio)

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your `FileInputStream` in a `GZIPInputStream` like so:

`InputStream input = new GZIPInputStream(yourCompressedInput);`

For compressing when writing, you should use the GZIPOutputStream.

Good luck.

Comment: No, you would use the channels to get a stream. But then again, this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335969/reading-a-gzip-file-from-a-filechannel-java-nio. You can find the answer there.