# How to download a partial file from s3 [Java]

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I often come across huge files in s3 buckets with gzip format. These are basically text files in gzip format, so I want to download a partial file (let's say few hundred lines).

I didn't found any option in **s3cmd** which allow me to download a partial file even if it a plain text file without any compression.

Following is the java code what I have right now, which again downloads the complete file, what else I should be doing here to download a partial file which is in gzip format.

```java
    String outPutFile = 'mylocalfile.txt';
    File file = new File(outPutFile);
    S3Object s3object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key));
    InputStream reader = new BufferedInputStream(s3object.getObjectContent());
    OutputStream writer = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
    int read = -1;

    while ((read = reader.read()) != -1) {
        writer.write(read);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GZIPInputStream reading line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1080394/1162305) helped me to solve my problem. So finally here is what I have.

```java
int numOfLinesRead = 0;
String outPutFile = 'mylocalfile.txt';
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(outPutFile);

S3Object s3object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key));
InputStream fileStream = new BufferedInputStream(s3object.getObjectContent());
gzipStream = new GZIPInputStream(fileStream);
decoder = new InputStreamReader(gzipStream, "UTF-8");
BufferedReader buffered = new BufferedReader(decoder);

while ((thisLine = buffered.readLine()) != null && numOfLinesRead < numOfLinesToRead) {
    writer.write(thisLine+'\n');
    numOfLinesRead++;
}
```