# How to read from GZIPInputstream

Tags: java

Scenario is to read a gzip file(.gz extension)

Got to know that there is GZIPInputStream class to handle this.

Here is the code to convert file object to GZIPStream.

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(FILENAME);
 GZIPInputStream gzis = new GZIPInputStream(fin);
```

Doubt is how to read content from this 'gzis' object?

Comment: I am confused, that is just an InputStream, you read it like any other InputStream.

Comment: you may be confusing zip and gzip, though.

Comment: Yeah its gzip not zip.I updated.

Comment: You read the GZIPInputStream in exactly the same way you'd read the FileInputStream if the data had not been GZipped. If binary, you read into byte arrays. If text, you wrap with an InputStreamReader, specifying the character encoding.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080381/gzipinputstream-reading-line-by-line

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Decode bytes from an InputStream, you can use an InputStreamReader. A BufferedReader will allow you to read your stream line by line.

**If the zip is a TextFile**

```
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseBytes);
GZIPInputStream gzis = new GZIPInputStream(bais);
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(gzis);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);

String readed;
while ((readed = in.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(readed);
}
```

As noticed in the comments. It will ignore the encoding, and perhaps not work always properly.

**Better Solution**

It will write the uncompressed data to the destinationPath

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(sourcePath);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destinationPath);
GZIPInputStream gzis = new GZIPInputStream(fis);
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int len = 0;

while ((len = gzis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
}

fos.close();
fis.close();
gzis.close();
```

Comment: Assuming the gzipped content is text, and not binary data.

Comment: This assumes the content is text, and composed of lines. And ignores which encoding could have been used

Comment: The content is text only. What you mean by ingores the encoding?

Comment: If the content is text only then use the first solution. It then just outputs the string. The second solution writes, the unzipped file to destination path.

Comment: @Andreas now satisfied. Thanks for the notice.

Comment: @njzk2 Now satisfied! Thanks for the notice

Comment: @Aajan In the first solution i assume that it'is text. Use the second solution to write it to the destination path.

Answer (score 2):

I recommended you to use [Apache Commons Compress API](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/)

add Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
</dependency>
```

then use `GZipCompressorInputStream` class, example described [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/examples.html)

Comment: Can u show some example @Eugene Lebedev

Comment: @Navigator https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/examples.html