# Sending & Receiving Large Data Packets with ChannelClient in WearOS

Tags: android, compression, wear-os, battery-saver

I use the [ChannelClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/ChannelClient) for the transmission of large data packets between a WearOS device and a smartphone. Does ChannelClient automatically compress the data during transmission, or would it be beneficial to manually compress the data beforehand?

Comment: I didn't work with this class. It seems, there is no compression going there, but it works with streams, so you should be able to plug in compression there. It will look something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/35789338/706456. Write data to input stream, which is written into compression stream, which is written into the client to send. You do the same in reverse on the receiving side. Compression may be a heavy operation on CPU, consider using some lightweight compression.